# tikz intersection of circle and line

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

If circle and line is a draw command as below, is it possible to get intersection? for this example, the C point now is hardcoded.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,convert={density=300,outext=.jpg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
 \coordinate (B) at (1,1.732);
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
 \draw (A) circle (1);
 \draw (A) -- (1,2);
 \draw (O) -- (B);
 \coordinate (C) at (0.5,0.861);//fix me with intersection of circle and line
 \draw (A) -- (C); 
 % annotation
 \draw[fill=red] (O) circle (1pt)  node[below left=0 of O] {O};
 \draw[fill=red] (A) circle (1pt)  node[below right=0 of A] {A};
 \draw[fill=red] (B) circle (1pt)  node[above right=0 of B] {B};
 \draw[fill=red] (C) circle (1pt)  node[above left=0 of C] {C};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @GroCo So I should not use draw command but use node command? Is it exactly the same to replace draw with node?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the tkz-euclide package. There is a command to find the intersection point of a line and a circle.

The following is from highschoolmathandchess.com:

tkzInterLC(A,B)(C,D) where (A,B) are points on the line and (C,D) is the center of a circle and a point on the circle.

Comment: The cited domain is for sale, at present...